# What do "Mac Ads Cleaner" and "Mac App Cleaner" do while installed?

Tags: malware, virus, macos, virus-removal

Recently I responded to a suggestion that I "upgrade Flash" on my macOS system only do end up with several applications running, and intruding into my browser and desktop that I did not (mean to) install:

- Mac Ads Cleaner
- Mac App Cleaner
- Porn Cleaner

I followed instructions I found online for removing these apps and believe they are gone (Bitdefender's virus and malware virus scan shows no remaining malicious software).

However, I wonder what they did while they were on my machine. What I could *see* is that they were very intrusive: launching themselves, setting themselves up to re-launch on start, resetting my browser's homepage to a spoof "safe" search engine — even popping up a window when they were installed by moving to the Trash. But I would like to know what else they did while installed *that I couldn't *see*.

What do these apps do? Have they done any lasting damage? Or are they only a nuisance while installed?

---

Note that this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/138606/35988). Here the question is what *these specific* (and common and well known) apps did when installed. (For example, did they capture passwords, erase files, etc.?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help! My home PC has been infected by a virus! What do I do now?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138606/help-my-home-pc-has-been-infected-by-a-virus-what-do-i-do-now)

Comment: @Anders: Not a duplicate (did you read the question?): this is about what these specific apps did when installed.