# What should I do if my Android was hacked?

Tags: android, mobile, phone

I know my Android phone was hacked and now, the hacker can take snaps with my front/back camera, register videos, view/send SMS and access everything on my phone. I can suppose he installed an .apk file but I didn't find any .apk files. What should I do?

Comment: Assuming you are correct you need to perform a factory reset and change any password you have entered on the device.

Comment: Kali does not hack things, people hack things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You deal with a phone infected with malware pretty much the same way [you deal with a computer infected by malware](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138606/help-my-home-pc-has-been-infected-by-a-virus-what-do-i-do-now) - you do a complete factory reset, wiping everything from the phone and reinstalling the OS. Don't expect that you will be able to surgically remove the malware. Most likely you will not, or at least you will not know if anything is left.

You may want to avoid using the phone before you do this, and especially avoid connecting it to anything else. You may also want to change any passwords you have entered on the infected device.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not sure, whether your phone was hacked or not, first of all,

1. Connect your phone to a proxy tool
2. Install it's certificate and intercept all the requests.
3. Check for any suspicious requests. **Don't intercept requests from gstatic or google.**

**OR**

> If you have root access

Install [greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify) and check for suspicious Apps.
If you see any such suspicious request, you can deal with it in a few ways.

> Method 1

1. Inside the request, you intercepted, you may get the app's name or a hint to which app is doing so. Though there is a possibility that it can be a malware
2. Go to Settings->Apps and search for the application. If you find it, uninstall it. **And you are good to go!**

> Method 2

Now, this one is pretty direct and is stated by almost all of the users. Give a factory reset to your phone. Erase all of your applications as well as data. **And you are good to go again.**

> Method 3

This one will work only if you have root access to your phone.

Install and open [greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify) and just check for the suspicious app. If you find any, just delete it. **And you are good to go again!**

You will find method 3 to be most effective in this case. Nonetheless other 2 should work just fine.