# Says HTTPS website (Apple and Netflix) are not private after opening port 443

Tags: tls, ssh

Every time I visit apple.com or netflix.com it says that the connection is not private and doesn't allow me to connect to it. I opened port 443 on my modem (as well as ports 8080 and 2222) so I would be able to ssh to my Raspberry Pi at home from the outside (I also use it to test my website on port 8080).

Ports 8080 and 2222 were open for a good 2 weeks and nothing happened to my Raspberry or home network. But just a few days after opening 443 those 2 sites stopped working.

The problem still persisted after closing the ports and disconnecting the Raspberry Pi from the network.

My questions are what are the security risks of opening ports and what can be done in my situation to fix the problem?

This is the certificate for all sites:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like your router screwed up the mapping and is somehow redirecting outbound HTTPS (443) connections to your Raspberry Pi. Try reset your router and see if that fixes it.

Comment: you opened ports for *incoming* connections, and you are experiencing problems with *outbound* connections - I wouldn't look at the opened ports as a problem - it might help if you actually included what the error actually is from your browser

Comment: @schroeder every browser from the pi, my laptop, my phone, and any device on the network shows this error. I tried to connect the raspberry directly to the modem and the same issue occurred.

Comment: I reset my modem and I still can't access either apple or Netflix

Comment: @schroeder could it be a phishing website? It also says eBay even tho Im trying to connect to apple.com...

Comment: I'm sorry, but if I am right, you might need to get a professional to help. Here is our general help on what to do next: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138606/help-my-home-pc-has-been-infected-by-a-virus-what-do-i-do-now

Comment: @schroeder I reset the modem and had the backup settings back on it and everything works fine now. I think whoever did this probably messed with the modem or my raspberry pi. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MichelBalamou I woudn't trust that computer at all as it is now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The security risks of opening ports are really about the risks of the ***services*** running on those ports. It is possible that someone discovered your test website and pwned your computer because your site had weaknesses (assuming that this is the same computer that you are seeing the error).

If this happened, then yes, they could have done *anything*, and an effect could be certificate errors on HTTPS sites.

In your specific case, because the certs are not legitimate, it looks like you have been pwned.