# got red screen while calling fake support number

Tags: malware

I called the number on the screen. The IT guy remotely accessed my laptop and showed me what he said were foreign IP addresses that proved i had been hacked. he then showed me a list of executable files that had been stopped. I grew suspicious when he said the fix was to get a network firewall security app for 931 dollars. when i questioned his insistence on my quick decision he hung up. long story short, i have no internet access or any other program access on that computer and would like to restore it. the only program that loads when i boot up is a dos shell that says administrator after the prompt

Comment: Absent any idea of what he did, the only real way to be sure that it's not compromised is to nuke it from orbit and start over.

Comment: @baldPrussian that's what I was going to suggest. The number on the screen is most likely linked with the original hack - sounds like a ransomware variation

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: This is a scam. Don't trust everything shown in your browser. See also https://www.computerworld.com/article/2469614/endpoint-security/scareware-scam-mimics-firefox-and-chrome-malicious-attack-warnings.html for similar attacks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help! My home PC has been infected by a virus! What do I do now?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138606/help-my-home-pc-has-been-infected-by-a-virus-what-do-i-do-now)

Comment: At this stage, your PC is probably pawned and should be treated as such.