# chrome is launched and tries to open a wierd website

Tags: malware, windows, web-browser, trojan, chromium

I have this wierd problem that once in a while (I guess mostly when I plug my laptop to adapter) chromium is lauched by itself and loads this wbesite:
http://gestyy.com/wPEFwy

I can guess that there might be a trojan or a cpu/gpu miner or another type of malware running on my system but windows defender does not complain about it.

how can I get rid of this?

I also need to know which process fires chromium? is there a way to tell what process is the cause of firing another process?

Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 10.0.16299 Build 16299

Comment: Sounds to me like the standard malware resources would be of use to you: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138606/help-my-home-pc-has-been-infected-by-a-virus-what-do-i-do-now

Comment: To add to everything, you can use free tools like sysinternals process explorer to see what launched the website. You'll see the website in the command line arguments used to start the browser.

Answer (score 2):

> how can I get rid of this?

You need to uninstall Chrome immediately, run a full AV scan (including searching for rootkits), and only after re-install chromium. Some mining scripts use JavaScript [within your browser to mine](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10320/how-useful-is-a-javascript-miner) - it sounds like this is what's happening.

> I also need to know which process fires chromium?  is there a way to tell what process is the cause of firing another process?

[This](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/determine-parent-process-of-running-process/) may help. It does require downloading other software. If you're not comfortable with that, try using the process manager and checking the startup programs.

Comment: Chromium is not Linux, Chromium is a browser. If instead you meant to say that Chromium _runs_ on Linux, that's true, but it also runs on many other platforms. He says he's using windows.

Comment: ah, I missed that. I've only ever see chromium on Linux, but yes, he does have that at the bottom. Will edit.

Comment: I ended up removing windows, now I am back at ubuntu :)

Comment: Glad to hear it! If I've answered your question, can you please mark it as "answered?"