# Refurbished laptop computer - any advice?

Tags: virus, keyloggers, spyware, trojan

I just recently bought a refurbished laptop. I have seen stories of refurbished phones being sold with spyware, trojans etc installed on them. My question is, what steps should I take (outside of running a virus protection scan) before i start using the laptop to ensure there is no spyware, trojans, keylogging, etc? And this second part question may be harder (or impossible) to answer, but is there a way to be absolutely certain it's a clean laptop?

Comment: Nuke it from orbit.

Comment: Who did you buy it from?  The OEM or a third party?

Comment: I would follow the advice of this post: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138606/help-my-home-pc-has-been-infected-by-a-virus-what-do-i-do-now/138617#138617

Comment: I got it from a third party, a "registered microsoft refurbisher"... not sure the credabilty of that but it sounds nice

Comment: Who is your adversary?

Comment: No one in particular, but with technology one must always stay vigilant and cautious :)

Answer (score 2):

Update the motherboard firmware, manually, and reinstall the OS, reformatting the drive. It's not a complete guarantee of security, but it will get rid of 99% of the likely threats.

By "refurbished", not just "used", do you mean a proper manufacturer refurbished item? In that case your risk is somewhat lower than with a plain used item, as the manufacturer won't deliberately install malware.

There is no way to be absolutely certain. Theoretically, if you were a high value target, someone could even install a hardware chip to spy on you.

Comment: It's not considered used but refurbished, I got it from a third party, a "registered microsoft refurbisher"

Answer (score 1):

@Therac got the basics - wipe and reinstall.  Hardware malware is less common but exists, so reinstalling firmware isn't crazy but may not be necessary depending on your experience/risk acceptance level.

I'm mainly just adding one note: your question implies that "new is safe" but this isn't actually true either.  There have been cases of new hardware/systems coming with malware pre-installed too!  Example:

https://www.zdnet.com/article/malware-found-on-new-hard-drives/