# (WMI Infections) Suspect behavior from scrcons.exe detected?

Tags: virus, antivirus, antimalware

In almost every five minutes, I come out of the AVG avg stop downloading files and do not know which program wants to download these files.

I have read this before **[WMI Infections](https://forum.eset.com/topic/12134-wmi-infections/)**

So, i opened this question because, i think this malware variant used WMI to maintain persistence.

I have read this too : [**Explained: WMI hijackers**](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/cybercrime/2016/10/explained-wmi-hijackers/)

[image]

> Effectively, the script to be executed is hidden from the user, and
>   the script (as a file) isn’t stored on the system. Which is why it is
>   considered as another fileless infection. WMI techniques were used by
>   malware like Stuxnet in the past.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help! My home PC has been infected by a virus! What do I do now?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138606/help-my-home-pc-has-been-infected-by-a-virus-what-do-i-do-now)

Comment: @Joshua.J it's not duplicate, please check my edit to understand why i have opened this question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target IP belongs to KRYPT TECHNOLOGIES, which is a cloud hosting company.

Their IPs are known to be used in an abusive manner:

- they are known for using and hosting ambiguous domain names
- they tend to also have malicious traffic and internet abuse trends
- many of their so called legitimate websites hosted by them are actually fronts for hosting virus’s and other malicious distributed files, attacks and other malicious activities
- BOTNET activities
- activities that have been monitored through their internet access has been Spam, Virus Activity, Hacking Attempts, as well as Malicious file distribution

Verdic: Virus/malware.

Recommended Actions: delete files, blacklist IP in firewall.