# PDF UrlMal-inf[Trj] Virus

Tags: malware, virus, pdf

When I create PDF file from my particular DOCX file, it gets infected with the virus. But if I create a new DOCX file and create PDF from that, it doesn't get infected with the virus.

I have tried to solve the issue with Malwarebytes but it didn't work. Only AVG and AVIRA antivirus detect this malware but rather than neutralizing it, it is removing the file.

Is there any way to remove this malware manually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help! My home PC has been infected by a virus! What do I do now?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138606/help-my-home-pc-has-been-infected-by-a-virus-what-do-i-do-now)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that. The PC is not infected: AVG/Avira has detected a link to a malicious site in the PDF. Easy to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The detection of `PDF.UrlMal-inf [Trj]` is related to the PDF contents: the file itself isn't harmful, but contains URLs (links) to sites that have been found malicious. That's why an empty file can never be infected with a `PDF.UrlMal-inf`.

1. Search your `.docx` file for hyperlinks.
2. Test these URLs with e.g. [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/home/url).
3. Manually remove the links that have been found malicious.
4. Convert the PDF again.

In order to neutralize the file, an AV would need to be able to create working PDF files.