# Attacked by ransomware that has encrypted and renamed all files with a .makop extension

Tags: file-encryption, decryption, ransomware

I've spent several hours searching the internet to see if anyone has cracked this encryption yet, but without any luck.  I don't want to reward criminals for their activity, but I do have a few files that I absolutely need. **Besides finding a decryptor or paying the ransom, do I have any other options for recovering my files?**  I have been able to successfully restore a couple of systems from backups, but my personal system wasn't backed up and has temporarily housed important files.

I'm somewhat familiar with best practices of backing up important files and/or saving to the cloud, but I will definitely be more vigilant in the future.  It was mostly due to the 'it will never happen to me' mindset.

Relevant information:

- I've identified how they got in, and have reset the password on that account (and all other accounts just in case).
- I did have malware bytes and sophos installed.  Looking at the Event Viewer, there are logs of both of these software being successfully uninstalled.
- The files are renamed like this: originalFileName.orig.[8-digit-hex].[ruthlessencry@qq.com].makop
- The ransom note file says to contact them at ruthlessencry@qq.com to pay them in bitcoins.
- They'll decrypt a couple of files for free, and then send me a scanner-decoder program after being paid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help! Ransomware encrypted my files. What do I do now?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/225873/help-ransomware-encrypted-my-files-what-do-i-do-now)

Comment: I did see that.  I'm hoping (against reason) that somehow somebody knows something about makop that I've been unable to find.

Comment: Unfortunately you know enough to answer your question. Unless you find a decryptor you're due to gauge the value of your data and whether you can loose it.