# How to decrypt encrypted data from .repl ransomware on Windows?

Tags: encryption, decryption, ransomware, virus-removal

My PC is infected with some sort of ransomware.

I managed to take out the root processes of the virus (which encrypt and change all document, images and video files to `*.repl` files) but recovering the infected data is a bit difficult and not many resources available online yet.

Comment: https://malwarewarrior.com/how-to-remove-repl-ransomware-and-decrypt-repl-files/ and https://howtofix.guide/repl-virus-removal/#How_to_decrypt_repl_files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help! Ransomware encrypted my files. What do I do now?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/225873/help-ransomware-encrypted-my-files-what-do-i-do-now)