# There's a virus in my explrorer.exe file in local disk C

Tags: malware, virus

I have a virus in my explorer.exe file. Because of that virus the desktop screen gets black sometimes. Then i have to open task manager, browse the explorer.exe file and open it. This solves the problem. However when i attempt to remove this virus, most of the antivirus don't detect it and those who do are not able to remove it and during this removal process the virus gets active again  and the screen goes black. I don't know how to remove this virus so please help me out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help! My home PC has been infected by a virus! What do I do now?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138606/help-my-home-pc-has-been-infected-by-a-virus-what-do-i-do-now)

Comment: I would actually describe this as `explorer.exe` crashing, and thus you no longer being able to use the desktop (which is run by explorer), Manually executing explorer.exe fixes it. Now, you need to figure out why explorer,exe is crashing (which may be due to a virus, but most likely it is not)