# Surfed Darkweb carelessly

Tags: virus, tor, virus-removal, drive-by-download, darknet

A while ago, I installed Tor app on my android (fully updated and Android 10) and with a free Vpn tried to open some sites listed on several blogs (like "best dark sites in 2020" or "dark websites for torrents" etc)(most were scams) and also one that claimed to be providing hidden news of world (basically conspiracy theorist). So, I didn't provided any single permission to tor (but it was on Standard security), neither gave any info anywhere. But I remember, that most of them had redirecting ads, and a couple of times Tor displayed a webpage of warning of hijack attempt etc. But I dismissed it foolishly due to no prior knowledge. Also, a couple of time I was asked for a download but I denied.

Now, after researching exhaustively I am worried that my phone may have been hacked or something. There are no symptoms, I upgraded to Android 11, two antivirus softwares - Malwarebytes and Bitdefender - were unable to find anything suspicious and there are no suspicious apps too. I also didn't find anything in Download folder. But still I am skeptical and worried.

Can there be a possibility of hacking or trojan (or something like BeEF, drive by download etc) . How can I identify it and fix it. And to what extent can an attack penetrate a phone? (considering I didn't accept or got any suspicious request or permission)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help! My home PC has been infected by a virus! What do I do now?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138606/help-my-home-pc-has-been-infected-by-a-virus-what-do-i-do-now)

Comment: The *"warnings of hijack attempt"* were probably fake and were intended to scare/trick you (or any gullible users) into downloading and running some shady "security" software and getting compromised. If the Tor browser can detect an attempt to hack your device, it can almost certainly also block the attempt (of course this excludes phishing pages, where the browser can only warn you).