# Can Android be hacked without ANY symptoms

Tags: virus, virus-removal, drive-by-download, darknet

The full story goes [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/244540/surfed-darkweb-carelessly)

In short, I surfed darkweb on android(updated android 10, now 11) carelessly and ignored some hijack warnings(2 of them) by Tor (warnings came in the form of a purple webpage that was supposed to be the page where automatic ad redirected) on a couple of ads.

Now, basically I did not found anything downloaded, nor did the antivirus softwares. Also, there are no unwanted apps. But I want to make sure nothing is going on there.

How can I spot the anomaly (if its there)?

Should I factory reset my phone?

Can my phone be rooted without me noticing anything?

Can a virus or spyware hide itself very smartly without any trace?

Comment: @vidarlo what do you mean? I posted that question too and provided its link in the question. My question here is asking for a different thing.

Comment: It's essentially the same question...

Comment: Please do not repost closed questions. We are not a malware removal site nor tech support. Malware can do anything the device can do, so everything you suggest is *possible*. What has actually happened to your phone is not something we can help with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is absolutely possible for a [zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-day_(computing)) [day](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/33314/235964) exploit to be used to infect an up-to-date device and root it. Its also absolutely possible for spyware to be installed that no anti-virus currently detects and that leaves no trace that an ordinary user would notice. Its also possible for malware to persist even after the device has been reset. **However, these all require a significant amount of skill and resources to be pulled off and are therefore less likely to occur in the wild.** Zero days are not cheap. Unless you are a high value target, its unlikely that anybody would waste the resources to infect you.