# I ran an exe file on my computer

Tags: malware, virus, trojan

I downloaded a crack file today, Idk why I thought its safe to run, now my pc is infected.
I already used Tronscript, kaspersky and hitman
what else do you guys suggest me to do?
thanks in advance.
VirusTotal: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/5fd3f17ef98f898595c8add5e11f193b577085e344d00527312e33a3ed56e29a

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138606/help-my-home-pc-has-been-infected-by-a-virus-what-do-i-do-now

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not tech support. The duplicate offers helpful advice.