# How to locate a malicious script in the Linux system

Tags: malware, ubuntu, netstat

I would like to ask for some directions to trace back to the original (malicious) script on my system (Ubuntu Server). I would try to be more specific if needed. If the question does not fit this stackexchange, then I will modify it.

In `netstat`'s output, the `PID/Program name` only showed "-" and the one next to it `1441/-bash`. While i can locate the PID of the latter, I have no idea to do that with the first one. These two processes would respawn after reboot.

To give more context, the two suspicious connections are from `198.251.80.207` and `157.230.4.227`. It seems like they are trying to mine XMR. I have got rid of their keys in `authorized_keys` but could not find a way to stop the established connection to port 50866 from foreign port 443 (`UFW` already blocked that IP in and out but somehow it can still establish a connection). I was able to block connection from my server to `157.230.4.227`, hence it only showed `SYN_SENT`.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 my_server_ip:50866       198.251.80.207:443      ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      1 my_server_ip:36730       157.230.4.227:8443      SYN_SENT    1441/-bash
```

UFW info

```
     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] Anywhere                   DENY IN     159.75.245.82             
[ 2] Anywhere                   DENY IN     45.137.21.134             
[ 3] 194.163.163.20             DENY IN     Anywhere                  
[ 4] Anywhere                   DENY IN     194.163.163.20            
[ 5] 155.94.171.66              DENY IN     Anywhere                  
[ 6] Anywhere                   DENY IN     155.94.171.66             
[ 7] 198.251.89.111             DENY IN     Anywhere                  
[ 8] Anywhere                   DENY IN     198.251.89.111            
[ 9] Anywhere                   DENY IN     88.99.242.92              
[10] Anywhere                   DENY IN     198.251.80.207            
[11] Anywhere                   DENY IN     157.230.4.227             
[12] 157.230.4.227              DENY IN     Anywhere                  
[13] 198.251.80.207             DENY IN     Anywhere                  
[14] 88.99.242.92               DENY IN     Anywhere
```

`ls -l /proc/1441`'s output, the `-bash` script got deleted right after reboot.

```
<snipped>
-r--r--r--   1 root root 0  1월 28 16:17 cpuset
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root 0  1월 28 16:06 cwd -> //
-r--------   1 root root 0  1월 28 16:17 environ
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root 0  1월 28 16:06 exe -> /bin/-bash (deleted)
dr-x------   2 root root 0  1월 28 16:05 fd/
dr-x------   2 root root 0  1월 28 16:17 fdinfo/
<snipped>
```

How to I find what script/process that triggered `exe` binary file above?

Comment: Even if you locate your malware, the original entry-point of the attack remains. Please remove your server from production, taking it offline if possible. Then you could do a forensic analysis of its content. When you have found the probable source of entry, you should [nuke your server from orbit](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/138606/127837).

Comment: I really appreciate this and this is what I would definitely do in production. This is my local server and I take this chance to learn more about malware traces.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are struggling after removing the crontab created by the malware, there is one more place you should look.

System services and start-up services are located in `/etc`. For example, in Ubuntu it should be something like `/etc/rc.local` file and `/etc/systemd/system`.

Check for suspicious scripts and remove them.